# Enable/disable commandLink using a boolean flag and ActionListener. JSF PrimeFaces

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

I am trying enable/disable a commandLink depending on a boolean flag. When a commandButton is clicked, I am trying to fix the boolean flag to false, and use the "disable" property of commanLink to fix disable=false

**commandLink is disabled onstart:**

```
<div align="right" style="display: block; float: right;">

  <p:commandLink id="buttonGuardar" action="#{vinculacionesGestionDetalleController.buttonGuardar}" update="@form" process="@form" styleClass="fa-commandlink fa-floppy-o" inmediate="true" disabled="#{vinculacionesGestionDetalleController.flagGuardar}">

    <h:outputText value="#{msg.guardar}" />
  </p:commandLink>

</div>
```

When this **commandButton is clicked**, I want to change the value of the boolean flag:

```
<p:commandButton id="validacionesValidarCodigoButton" actionListener="#{vinculacionesGestionDetalleController.buttonValidar}" value="Validar" styleClass="searchButton" icon="fa fa-button fa-check-circle" process="@form" style="margin-left: 20px;">
</p:commandButton>
```

**Controller:**

```
private boolean flagGuardar = true;

public void buttonValidar(ActionEvent event) {

  Boolean validacion = false;
  validacion = vinculacionesService.validarCodigo(vinculacionLaboral.getCodigo());

  if (validacion == true) {
    super.addMessageInfo("listas_gestion_info_titulo",
      "vinculaciones_gestion_detalle_validacion_success");
    flagValidacion = true;
    //setFlagGuardar(false);
    flagGuardar = false;
  } else {
    super.addMessageError("listas_gestion_info_titulo",
      "vinculaciones_gestion_detalle_validacion_unsuccess");
    flagValidacion = false;
    //setFlagGuardar(true);
    flagGuardar = true;
  }
  //return flagValidacion;
}
```

What I am doing wrong?

Thank you.

Comment: What happens when you add `update="@form"` to the button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
   <p:commandButton id="validacionesValidarCodigoButton" actionListener="#{vinculacionesGestionDetalleController.buttonValidar}" value="Validar" styleClass="searchButton" icon="fa fa-button fa-check-circle" update="buttonGuardar" style="margin-left: 20px;">
    </p:commandButton>
```